# Installing mysql on ubuntu

Tags: mysql

I have downloaded the mysql server tar file for ubuntu.
I tried installing it by refering steps given on internet but it never worked.
How can i install it manually in easy way.
How to start mysql after installing it

Comment: Ok just give me the steps to install it manually without software center, as i do not have internet.

Comment: @Manishsakpal Please extract your tar file to your /home and open a terminal and enter the folder like this `cd /home/user/mysqlfolder/you/extracted`,  change the path of course, when in the folder type `ls` and add all the output to yor question please.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to build the source, it is in the repos, open a terminal and run

```
sudo apt-get install mysql-server
```

MySQL will start automatically

**Building from source**

You can build mysql manually from source by following the steps from the MySQL website:

> ```
> # Preconfiguration setup
> groupadd mysql
> useradd -g mysql mysql
> # Beginning of source-build specific instructions
> tar zxvf mysql-VERSION.tar.gz
> cd mysql-VERSION
> ./configure --prefix=/usr/local/mysql
> make
> make install
> # End of source-build specific instructions
> # Postinstallation setup
> cd /usr/local/mysql
> chown -R mysql .
> chgrp -R mysql .
> bin/mysql_install_db --user=mysql
> chown -R root .
> chown -R mysql var
> # Next command is optional
> cp support-files/my-medium.cnf /etc/my.cnf
> bin/mysqld_safe --user=mysql &
> # Next command is optional
> cp support-files/mysql.server /etc/init.d/mysql.server
> ```
>
> https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/installing-source-distribution.html

Comment: I dont have internet on laptop, i only have mysql tar file downloaded.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you try simple method? :-). Install from Software Centre and let it do installation for you

Open `Software Centre` and search for `mysql` and from the list install `MySQL Server`

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can use `fpm` to build packages from source. You can find the tutorial to use `fpm` in [here](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-use-fpm-to-easily-create-packages-in-multiple-formats)